# Python attribute access error

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I am trying to customize attribute access in a class (python2.7).  Say I define the following class:

```
class testAttrAccess(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {"attr1":"value1","attr2":"value2"}

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        try:
            return self.data[name]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        raise AttributeError
```

Then I get:

```
In [85]: a = testAttrAccess()

In [86]: a.attr2
Out[86]: 'value2'

In [87]: a.__getattr__('attr2')
Out[87]: 'value2'

In [88]: a.__getattribute__('attr2')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/laserson/temp/<ipython console> in <module>()

AttributeError: 'testAttrAccess' object has no attribute 'attr2'
```

However, [according to the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes)

> If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an `AttributeError`.

So if `__getattribute__()` is raising an `AttributeError`, then why isn't `__getattr__()` being called and returning the proper value?

Answer (score 1):

`__getattribute__()` is still default, so it is reaching for `self.attr2` instead of `self.data['attr2']`

Comment: oh, but then why `a.attr2` works.  maybes thats not it... good question

Comment: `a.attr2` works precisely because `attr2` doesn't exist and thus `__getattr__` is invoked. And the default `__getattribute__` obviously doesn't invoke `__getattr__`.

Comment: right, i follow.  thanks for making it clear, i was second guessing myself for a minute

Answer (score 1):

```
So if __getattribute__() is raising an AttributeError, then why isn't __getattr__() being called and returning the proper value?
```

That only applies if python is calling `__getattribute__` for you as a part of normal attribute access, not if you call `__getattribute__` yourself. Basically, you should *almost* never call a python method of the form `__foo__` Such methods are used to implement behaviors depended on by other operations.

Answer (score 0):

`a.__getattr__` gets called only if the attribute is not found in `a.__dict__`.

`a.__getattribute__` is called in all cases, if it is defined.

As you know, `a.__getattribute__(attr)` is syntactic sugar for `type(a).__getattribute__(a, attr)`, but since this method is not defined in `testAttrAccess`, the parent method `object.__getattribute__(a, attr)` is called. From your results we can then conclude that it is not `object.__getattribute__` that calls `__getattr__`. Probably the interpreter takes care of that.

You can make your program work by changing it like this:

```
class testAttrAccess(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {"attr1": "value1", "attr2": "value2"}

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except AttributeError:
            if name == "__getattr__":
                return object.__getattribute__(self, "__getattribute__")
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, "data")[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError
a = testAttrAccess()

print a.attr2
print a.__getattr__('attr2')
print a.__getattribute__('attr2')
print a.qwerty
```

Output:

```
value2
value2
value2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in 
    print a.qwerty
  File "test.py", line 13, in __getattribute__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

Comment: I was under the impression that whenever one wants to override attribute access to do something other than the default, they should only override `__getattr__()` and not `__getattribute__()`.  Is this correct?  Are there any hidden side-effects from the implementation you are proposing above?

Comment: Please see the answer I contributed as well.  I would appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @lazyr, this solution seems to work too.  It seems simpler to me...does it raise any red flags to anyone?

```
class testAttrAccess(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {"attr1":"value1","attr2":"value2"}

    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            return self.data[name]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        raise AttributeError
```

The following session gives:

```
In [108]: a = testAttrAccess()

In [109]: a.attr2
Out[109]: 'value2'

In [110]: a.__getattribute__('attr2')
Out[110]: 'value2'

In [111]: a.__getattr__('attr2')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/laserson/temp/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Users/laserson/temp/<ipython console> in __getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 

In [112]: a.qwerty
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/laserson/temp/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Users/laserson/temp/<ipython console> in __getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError:
```

Comment: `__getattribute__` is called for *every* non-magic method (`__add__', '__repr__`, etc.) so will have a big performance hit, as well as being completely unnecessary for what you want -- your original code using `__getattr__` is appropriate for what you want to do.